# How to combine the result of SQL server table rows using bitwise operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is

```
ID | RoleID | PermissionName | CanRead | CanWrite | CanUpdate |
 1 |      1 | Page1          |    1    |    0     |     1     |
 2 |      1 | Page2          |    1    |    0     |     0     |
 3 |      2 | Page1          |    0    |    1     |     0     |
 4 |      2 | Page2          |    1    |    0     |     1     |
```

If a user has 2 roles ex: RoleID 1, 2

So he has Read, Write, Update for Page1 and Read&Update for Page2 PermissionName

If I pass role ids to a stored procedure how to get the combined result as like below?

Ex:

```
PermissionName | CanRead | CanWrite | CanUpdate |
      Page1    |    1    |     1    |     1     |
      Page2    |    1    |     0    |     1     |
```

and the user may have n number of roles, according to the roles he is having list the combined permissions for each PermissionName

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT PermissionName, 
CASE WHEN sum(CanRead)   = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CanRead, 
CASE WHEN sum(CanWrite)  = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CanWrite, 
CASE WHEN sum(CanUpdate) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CanUpdate 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID = DesiredId 
GROUP BY PermissionName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your stored procedure

```
Declare @canRead int
Declare @canWrite int
Declare @canUpdate int

SELECT
    Case canRead = 1 then @canread = @canRead + 1  
    END canRead 
FROM 
    yourtablename 
WHERE 
    id = desiredID

SELECT 
    permissionName, 
    Case @canReasd >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END canRead 
FROM yourTableName 
WHERE id = desiredID
```